# Why is fromkeys a method rather than a built-in function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, methods, namespaces

Why is the `fromkeys` method of the `dict` class a method of the class rather than a stand alone built-in function?

As much as I'm aware, it only returns a new dictionary based on the parameters passed to the method, and is not impacted by the class instance (dictionary) it is called from. The usual implementation just uses the class name `dict` directly rather than specifying a class instance in the first place.

I've tried the following statements but they all have consistently ignored the class instance as I mentioned.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys((1,2))

{1: None, 2: None}

>>> {1: "Hey"}.fromkeys((1,2))

{1: None, 2: None}

>>> {1: "Hey"}.fromkeys((2,))

{2: None}
```

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) also doesn't mention anything more than what the parameters do. It does not mention any use of the class instance but does not declare its purposelessness either.

I believe the reason is probably related to the namespace management. A function `fromkeys` created by the user will not affect the built-in class method this way, right?

I just wanna make sure I've not missed out any purpose the class instance could have, to avoid future bugs in my codes

Comment: Why *would* it be a stand-alone function? Imaging reading a code that has the line `fromkeys((1, 2))`. What does it do? `fromkeys` what?

Comment: Also, `type.alternative_way_to_build_type(args)` is a very popular idiom in many OOP languages

Comment: @DeepSpace If it's gonna be a standalone function, it doesn't necessarily need to carry the same name. It could be named `dict_fromkeys` for example. We can also consider modifying the implementation to suit it accordingly. But thanks for mentioning that it's a popular thing. As of right now, I have only learnt Python and have seen this for dictionaries only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `dict.from_keys` only relies on `dict` itself and the arguments passed to the function. It doesn't use any of the information stored in an existing instance, so there is no reason to supply one.

As for why it is not a function, `dict.from_keys` can still work for *subclasses* of `dict` without having to do anything differently.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> type(OrderedDict.fromkeys([1,2,3]))
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

`Counter.fromkeys` won't work, but that's because `Counter.fromkeys` is specifically *overriden* to suggest an alternative.

---

Roughly speaking, you can think of `dict.fromkeys` as being implemented like this:

```
@classmethod
def fromkeys(cls, keys, value=None):
    return cls((k, value) for k in keys)
```

A call like

```
{'a': 1}.fromkeys(['b'])
```

is equivalent to

```
dict.fromkeys(dict, ['b'])  # First argument is type({'a': 1}), not dict
```

Comment: So to clarify, it doesn't matter which dictionary we call the method from right?

Comment: Right. `dict.fromkeys` uses its first argument to decide what to instantiate, rather than strictly creating a `dict`. A class method invoked by an instance of a class still receives the class, not the instance, as its first argument.

Comment: Are you implying that there are other classes that have a fromkeys method?

Comment: I'm not *denying* it. But `OrderedDict` doesn't have to define its own `fromkeys` method in order for `dict.fromkeys` to return an `OrderedDict`. `fromkeys` is defined *in* the class `dict`, but it is not *specific* to `dict`.